# Шифрование файлов с клиента на сервер python

Tags: python, сеть

Есть программа клиент/сервер, файлы со стороны клиента передаются на сервер, если были внесены изменения. Как правильно зашифровать файлы, чтобы после их передачи серверу, они на нем лежали зашифрованными (при этом они остаются незашифрованными на стороне клиента, и сервер не знает ключ для дешифрования)? т.е. если кто-то взломает сервер, они не могут воспользоваться этими файлами. Не могу найти приемеры для питона python, так что если есть какие-то примеры(особенно, используя OpenPGP) и как вообще это делать, было бы здорово.

Конкретно вопрос в том, что для посылки файла от клиента серверу и чтобы на сервер они загружались зашифрованными и выгружались с сервера на клиент-дешефрованными, если воспользоваться AES, то как? какой модификацией? И другие рекоммендации в комментариях-как ими пользоваться?

Comment: Берете AES, например, и шифруете.

Comment: Я бы просто через `os.system` или `os.popen` запускал какой-нибудь `gpg2` и его вывод отправлял на сервер любым удобным способом

Comment: Деталей не хватает. Вы хотите клон Tresorit создать? (более безопасный Dropbox аналог). Или вы хотите Tarsnap создать или другие вариации на тему типа SpiderOak?

Comment: @jfs, честно говоря, что о Tresorit, что о SpiderOak, первый раз слышу, поэтому и спрашиваю как это делать (даже AES, первый раз соображаю как делать). Изначально задание-сделать прогу типа Dropbox.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьяновl спасибо за подсказку. Ищу толковые примеры для применения AES.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, что откликнулисью Если у вас есть пример как   os.system или os.popen использовать для шифрования, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: В каком контексте *"задание—сделать прогу типа Dropbox"*? (Для образования?)

Comment: @jfs, да, изучаем networking,только примеров не дают как делать. Да и python я только начал изучать, просто надо было выбирать между С и питоном, в питоне это показалось чуть адекватнее.

Comment: @Neoni возможно от вас ожидают что вы воспользуетесь готовым API чтобы реализовать требуемую функциональность (к примеру посмотрите есть ли у boxcryptor Питон или web API). Потому что пытаться с нуля подобный сервис реализовывать—это огромная работа.

Comment: @jfs, не, можно только библиотеками пользоваться.

Comment: @Neoni: что значит *"можно только библиотеками пользоваться"* К примеру можно ли `dropbox` библиотекой воспользоваться? [пример кода на Питоне по загрузке локальной директории в Dropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py)

Comment: @jfs задание само по себе- сделать программу типа dropbox, поэтому их библиотекой нельзя пользоваться.

Comment: @Neoni очевидно, что на каком-то уровне вы обязаны чужим кодом воспользоваться, что вам не надо [из транзисторов компьютер собирать и с нуля весь код писать](http://www.nand2tetris.org/). Чтобы быстро что-то рабочее получить, доверьте логины, авторизацию, управление правами доступа и ключами, локальное шифрование, синхронизацию данных с удалённым сервером уже существующим сервисам—ваш код просто всё вместе склеивает—Питон для этого хорошо подходит...

Comment: ...[продолжение] Когда пользовательский интерфейс и желаемая функциональность устаканится, посмотрев какие ограничения сервисы имеют и почему, на какие компромиссы между удобством, безопасностью, и эффективностью им пришлось пойти, вы можете более ясно свою архитектуру, реализацию частей порождать, более информировано. Это сверху вниз подход...

Comment: ...[продолжение] Одновременно можно снизу вверх систему строить: пополняйте свой арсенал инструментов, к примеру научитесь блок данных шифровать/расшифровывать, используя разные подходы (забыв на время о файлах, группах пользователей, разрешениях на папки, синхронизации итд) или наоборот научитесь скачивать, закачивать изменяющиеся блоки данных как есть (забыв как они создаются, зашифрованы или нет)—концентрируясь на одной узкой задаче за раз. Столкнувшись с конкретными трудностями, вы можете здесь задать более сфокусированные вопросы.

Comment: @jfs спасибо. В принципе, так и получается, что я делаю снизу вверх, просто бывает и для кого-то простые вещи не получаются, потому что я вообще только начал учить python, а тут такие задания. А что вы порекомендуете использовать для логинов, авторизации, управления правами доступа и ключами, локального шифрования, синхронизации данных с удалённым сервером? Например, для шифрования нам было рекомендовано использовать OpenPGP (мне это не о чем не говорит, если честно, как это программировать, я имею ввиду), а для защиты передачи данных-OpenSSL, ну с этим хотя бы я разобрался более менее.

Comment: @Neoni: *"что порекомендуете"*: это не одна какая то библиотека, это набор библиотек/сервисов, которые вы *под свои* нужды выбираете и на коленке склеиваете, чтобы прототип быстро получить. *"я вообще только начал учить python"*--может быть всё что от вас просят можно в баше с помощью gpg2 и curl команд на клиенте реализовать и простеньким https сервером, который позволяет файлы загружать на сервере. Не бойтесь уточнить, что от вас хотят у того кто задание дал.